# MockFileSessionStorage on non-test workflow

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I encountered the **"Failed to start session"** error during conducting a PHPUnit test on my script. The resolution I made is this:

From this:

`$session = new Session();`

to:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MockFileSessionStorage;
$session = new Session(new MockFileSessionStorage());
```

It works now, however, my concern is that do I need to put the `new MockFileSessionsStorage())` everytime I test only? Or I can simply leave it there and won't affect my non-test workflow?

Comment: This configuration is often Made in the config_test.yml files

Comment: I don't get it, can you explain more?

Comment: Hi @Leandro, sorry for my english, I say that usually, for functional test purpose, the session is mocked in the same way BUT this configuration is stored in the config_test.yml files, as example in [this demo project](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/app/config/config_test.yml#L7)